# Matlab : How to check if two images are similar to each other

Tags: matlab, image-processing, correlation

I have coloured images of size 20 by 20. The objective is that :

based on a query, I need to check which recalled image is the closest match to the query. For example, let 10 images be the recalled ones. Out of the 10 recalled images, I  need to find the closest match to the query.

I was thinking of using the correlation between the images. One can use the Correlation coefficient - higher the value, more is the correlation between pixel values. (Please correct me where wrong).

`R = corr2(A,B1)` will compute the correlation coefficient between A and B where A is the query, B1 is the first recalled image image of the same size. I used the above command for colored images but I got the result `R = NaN`. How do I solve this problem for colored and gray scale. Thank you.

This is the QUERY IMAGE
[image: Query Image]

The other image(recalled / retrieved B1)
[image: Recal]

UPDATE : Code for testing correlation of an image with itself from a databasae called patches.mat (patches is the database. It consists of 59500 20x20 patches, reshaped into 400-dimensional column vectors,
taken from a bunch of motorcycle images; I am using the 50 th example as the query image)

```
img_query = imagesc(reshape(patches(:,50),20,20));
colormap gray;axis image;

R = corr2(img_query,img_query)
```

Answer = NaN

Comment: The NaN most likely indicates a division by zero. This might occur, for example, if one of the images is a uniform color (for example, solid white or solid black). On an unrelated note, you might want to downsample your images to get a better match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because one of the images is black or includes a single color, meaning that all the values of the matrix are similar. Check the following examples:

```
I = imread('pout.tif');
J = I*0;                     % create a black image
R = corr2(I,J);

R = 
   NaN


I = imread('pout.tif');
J = 255*ones(size(I));         % create a white image
R = corr2(I,J);

R = 
   NaN
```

---

**Update**

It should work in your case, as you can see in the following example, it works perfectly:

```
I1 = abs(255*(rand(10,10));
I2 = abs(255*(rand(10,10));
corr2(I1,I2)

ans =

   0.0713
```

[image]

Even with the images you have shared, it is working for me. To find out your problem, you have to either share a part of your code, or post images as they are, not saved images (with a size 420x560x3).

**Note:** you cannot have images including more than 1 layer.

---

> **Your code shows that you are using the handle of the image instead of the image itself.**

---

Test this:

```
I = reshape(patches(:,50),20,20);
corr2(I,I)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So, for colored images corr2() can be used? I have uploaded the Query and the recalled image. Could you please have a look? The image is from a database consisting of  samples of 59500 20x20 greylevel image patches. The images consist of shades of gray, so why does correlation not work? Is there any other way statistically to show how close the images are to each other ?

Comment: Thank you once again for the updates. I have provided the code that I used to do the calculation. Really appreciate your time and effort. Thank you

Comment: @SKM see the updates. By the way in this site, upvoting is the same meaning as thank you!

Comment: I have upvoted mainly due to the lack of the desire seen by the OP.  Great post. +1.

Comment: @NKN: I was using imagesc() without knowing that it returns the image handle. Thank you for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

I would try also the Universal Quality Index by Wang which gives you a 1.0 if both images are equal, and less in other cases with spatial indication where they differ, think of one image as reference, the other as a degraded one relative to the first one. See http://www.cns.nyu.edu/~zwang/files/research/quality_index/demo.html